# pandas read dictionary with nested dict to data frame

Tags: pandas

I have a set of data in a python dict with a nested dict and want to transform it into an Pandas DF.

The data looks like this:

```
dct = {"123": {"street": "Sesame Street",
               "zip": "12345",
               "city": "TV Town",
               },
       "456": {"street": "ElmStreet",
               "zip": "87654",
               "city": "Freddys Town"},
       }
```

And I want a data frame like this:

| street | zip | city | id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Sesame Street | 12345 | TV Town | 123 |
| Elm Street | 87654 | Freddys Town | 456 |

How do I get the keys:values in the nested dict as columns in my DF?

What I got is the, but that is not what I wanted:

```
    123           456
street  Sesame Street     ElmStreet
zip             12345         87654
city          TV Town  Freddys Town
```

Answer (score 2):

You could read as index-oriented dictionary, then [`reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dct, orient='index').rename_axis('id').reset_index()
```

Output:

```
    id         street    zip          city
0  123  Sesame Street  12345       TV Town
1  456      ElmStreet  87654  Freddys Town
```